# Factorials in Sigma Notation

Tags: summation, factorial

Geometric Series one would use $S_n = \dfrac{a_1\cdot (1 - r^n)}{(1 -r)}$.
Arithmetic Series one would use $S_n = \dfrac{n\cdot (a_1 + a_n)}{2}$.
But how would I convert a sigma notation problem with factorials in it to an equation?
For example
$$
\sum_1^n \frac{i}{ (i + 1)!}
$$

How do I convert this into an equation.  (In particular I am trying to create another equation and use induction to prove that the two equations equal each other but that is just the application of why I need to find another way of writing this formula and if it was dealing with Geometric Series or Arithmetic Series I could do it but with factorials I am stuck.)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to write $\dfrac{i}{(i+1)!} = \dfrac{1}{i!} - \dfrac{1}{(i+1)!}$ and use telescope. So the use of either geometric or arithmetic sequence formulas is not necessary.

Comment: Whats a good link to read on "telescope" or what should I search for in order to find the meaning of it?  Second, I see that they equal each other and yes what is the trick?  How did you do this?

Comment: Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series